# How to allow commas in makecert.exe when creating a certificate?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, makecert

I try to use makecert.exe to create a certificate but it shows like this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>makecert -ss TESTCOM -n CN="TESTCOM FOR Co.,Ltd." -sv E:\markcab\TEST.pvk -r

E:\markcab\TEST.cer Error:CryptCertStrToNameW failed => 0x80092023 (-2146885597) Failed`

I know it caused by the comma contained in CN="TEST Co.,Ltd" , but I must to use the comma in this command, how could I do?

Comment: If you are not bound to use makecert.exe then use [xca](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it at once.

Comment: Beware that makecert tool is deprecated and not recommended for use anymore: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include a coma, you have to enclose your CN with quote and add '\' before and after the CN value

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>makecert -ss TESTCOM -n "CN=\"TESTCOM FOR Co.,Ltd.\"" -sv E:\markcab\TEST.pvk -r
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's work for me. I've spent a lot of time on this problem. I had never thought about this way before. Awesome :D